# Python Dictionary of DefaultDicts

Tags: python

I am trying to build a dictionary containing defaultdicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {
'first_key':defaultdict(list)
}

my_dict['first_key'].extend('add this to list')
```

...but that returns: `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sooo... This is it: you can't `extend` `DefaultDict`s...

Comment: Perhaps you want simply `my_dict = defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: simply change to my_dict = defaultdict(list) if you want to use list upon not set key.

Comment: Down voted? Yeesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you want a dictionary of defaultdicts for this. What you're trying to do is easily accomplished using the built-in `dict` method [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> my_dict.setdefault('numbers', []).extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> my_dict
{u'numbers': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> my_dict.setdefault('numbers', []).append(4)
>>> my_dict
{u'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

`setdefault` takes a (possibly missing) key and a default to initialize it to if it *is* missing. If the key is already there, it just returns it.

As John Kugelman points out in comments, this can also be accomplished using `defaultdict` in the normal way:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> my_dict['numbers'].extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'numbers': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> my_dict['numbers'].append(4)
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Comment: Why do you think OP does not want to use `defaultdict` but instead use `setdefault`?

Comment: @tobias_k: Typo. Meant "dictionary of defaultdicts", which it now says. This answer went a little off-track from my original intention since good comments discussing yet-to-be-written parts were cropping up while I was doing FGITW edits.